# std::out_of_range: vector::_M_range_check

Tags: c++, vector

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

struct TeamS 
{
    int ID;
    string MEMBERS[3];
};
//Vector initialization
void Initialize (vector<TeamS> & TeamV, const int id[], const string m[][3], int arraySize)
{
    for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    {
        TeamV.at(i).ID = id[i];
        for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
        {   
            TeamV.at(i).MEMBERS[j]=m[i][j];

        }
    }
}

void printList (const vector <TeamS>& TeamV)
{
     for(int i=0 ; i<4; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Information for team "<<i<<endl;
        cout<<TeamV[i].ID;
        for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++)
        {   
            cout<<"      "<<TeamV[i].MEMBERS[j]<<"     ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    short int choice;
    cout<<"Starting Initialization"<<endl;
    vector<TeamS> TeamV;
    const int ID [4] ={ 123, 321, 456, 789};
    const string MEMBERS [4] [3] =  {    {"Sarah", "Joe", "John"}, {"Chris", "Kevin", "James"}, {"Tom", "Kim", "Emily"}, {"Jill", "Jason", "Jim"}   };
    cout<<"Ending Initialization"<<endl;
    Initialize (TeamV, ID ,MEMBERS, 4);
    cout<<"**** Team List **** "<<endl;
    //printList(TeamV);
    cout<<"************************************************************************"<<endl;

    while(1)
    {
    cout<<"Enter 1 to see a list of teams"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 2 to add a team to the list"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 3 to search for a team using an ID"<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter 4 to end the program"<<endl;
    cout<<endl<<"Enter Choice : ";
    cin>>choice;
    if(choice == 1)
              {  printList(TeamV);  }
    else if(choice == 2)
              {                     }
    else if(choice ==3 )
              {                     }
    else if(choice == 4)
              {  exit(0);           }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I compile this, it's give me the error terminating program 'std:out_of_range'
what<>: vector::_M_range_check
I can't find the problem in my code but take a look maybe you got something

Answer (score 2):

At no point are you actually adding anything onto your vector. Your `Initialize()` starts with:

```
TeamV.at(i).ID = id[i];
```

But if `TeamV` is empty, that'll throw `out_of_range`. You probably meant to do:

```
TeamV.push_back(TeamS()); // NOW, there's something in it
TeamV[i].ID = id[i];
```

Even better to add a constructor to `TeamS` that takes an id and some members, so that the loop can just be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    TeamV.push_back(TeamS(id[i], m[i]));
}
```

Or in C++11:

```
std::vector<TeamS> TeamV{
    {123, {"Sarah", "Joe", "John"}},
    {321, {"Chris", "Kevin", "James"}},
    ...
};
```

Comment: Already got my upvote, but I'd add in how to do away with the init routine entirely and do a static vector init.

Comment: Addendum: @NomanShakoor This will probably be the least troublesome way to define the constructor: `TeamS(int id,const string (&members)[3])`. It won't catch a team that is too small, but will prevent overrunning the MEMBERS array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you create your vector TeamV in your main function and leave it empty. It has no elements. But then you call `Initialize(TeamV,...)`. In this
function you try to access the elements of TeamV via `at()`, but it's empty!